# Android: How to change the background of the menu item in the toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, fragment

You need to change the background of the ~`showAsAction = always` element as in the example.

[image]

I tried to make custom xml through a layer-list with a background and an icon, but as a result, the background was only inside the icon, and not around the entire perimeter of the item in the menu. Also tried `android(app):background`, `android(app):itemBackground`, but it`s dont work

My menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_filter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_slider"
    app:iconTint="@color/green"
    android:iconTint="@color/green"
    android:title="filters"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    />
```

My adding menu in fragment

```
val menuHost: MenuHost = binding.searchAnimeToolbar
    menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
            val menuFilterButton = menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter)


        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            if(menuItem.itemId == R.id.action_filter) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            return true
        }
    }, viewLifecycleOwner)
```

**Update:**
This method with the addition of a separate drawable is not suitable, because it is necessary to set the background for the menu item, and not for the icon.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/opacity_green"/>
                <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_slider">
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a drawable for your menu item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable" />
</selector>
```

Then put it as icon for Menu Item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <item android:id="@+id/itemTodo"
        android:icon="@drawable/item_selector"
        android:title="TODO"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Hope it helps you. Happy coding!

Comment: Hi, it works, but this is not the behavior I would like to see.
Your method recolors the background of the image and processes the behavior when clicked, and so on.
But I need the background to be wider than the icon (as shown by the red outline in the picture) That is, I filled in the background of the menu item, and not the background of the icon

What i need
[link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/703922797856161913/1046746945059831818/image.png)

What i get
[link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/703922797856161913/1046747455896690738/image.png)

Comment: You can use shape instead of selector with required properties (Width,Height,Color, etc.) for desired background.

Comment: Apart for customizing menu items you can make custom toolbar as well as per your design that can resolve the issue.